# How do I add a pause in between the "how are you" and the "I'm great thanks" in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, notepad

So, I wrote this in notepad and i put it into the startup folder so when i turn my computer on it says "welcome to your pc, shell. How are to and i'm great thanks." So i want my laptop to wait a few seconds after the "how are you" and then say "I'm great thanks"
any suggestions?

```
    Dim speaks, speech
    speaks="Welcome to your PC, Shell. How are you?im great thanks"
    Set speech=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
    speech.Speak speaks
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ideally you would use split that text into 2 different parts and use the SpVoice pause method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Insert `WScript.Sleep TimeInMilliSecs` ([a](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t81adfd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [b](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156589.aspx)) at the appropriate places.

Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim speech : Set speech = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
speech.Speak "Welcome to your PC, Shell. How are you?"
WScript.Sleep 1500
speech.Speak "I am great, thanks."
```